# Compare two voice in android

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice-comparison

I am working on one voice messaging application, I need to compare two voice like,

1. Register with app by record your voice
2. Sent voice message to
       another user by record voice, but first need to compare this voice
       to recorded voice in profile.

Its for security purpose and need to know recorded message is from specific user or not.

I tried :

[Compare two sound in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213090/compare-two-sound-in-android)

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/274280-using-fft-to-compare-two-audio-files-and-then-realtime-comparison/

But not getting idea about voice Comparison.

Please share if anybody know about the same. Didn't find any sample to do this.

Answer (score 13):

Since you indicated it's for security purpose, I'd like to first share a few things on voice biometry :-)

The problem with authenticating someone is that you'd need to be sure he was actually there saying the things that were recorded... and that's a whole different level of complexity than merely comparing voice characteristics.

Algorithms extracting voice features from a sample and later calculating the distance between a new sample and the first one can easily be fooled by a recording made up by an attacker.

Since in your case there's a human recipient, creating a message made up of chopped words or sentences from random conversations is actually quite difficult and time consuming. But not completely impossible...

There are very good sounding softwares created for the music industry that will e.g. take some voice audio input and make it sound (intonation and time wise) like a second audio sample (a guide, made by the fraudster). Vocalign Pro by SynchroArts does this to help get perfect backing vocal tracks. You could further tweak the audio by hand using other voice editing softwares and achieve an acceptable level of quality that wouldn't be immediately detected by the recipient.

Depending on what the attacker wants your user to say, the process complexity could range from an hour to a day provided he has all the recording material he wants...

To fight against this type of attack, you need to detect the audio sample has been edited. The digital edition will leave unnatural traces. E.g. in the background noise surrounding the voice.

AFAICT, only the best commercial softwares achieve this level security check, but I can't tell how far they go in the detection of such edits.

From a pure security perspective, you'd also need to be sure the device was not compromised. So these voice verification check should happen server side and not on the phone itself.

Please note these are general considerations and it all depends on what sort of security measures you actually need for your use case. My car alarm is certainly not unbreakable but it helps raising the bar so fewer attackers could potentially steal it...

Another thing to consider is that biometry is by definition a statistical process and it will yield a certain percentage of false positives and false negatives. By changing the acceptance threshold, you'll be able to lower one of them at the cost of raising the other.

Selecting an appropriate threshold will require you to have a fair amount of test data. Say 1 minute recording of at least 200 speakers to start getting a picture.

One more thing I think you'll need to consider is the inherent variability of the human voice. People may be sick which in some cases might render the voice unrecognizable. Also the emotional state might play a role: sadness or anger will yield different sounding voices...

And last but not least, the surrounding noise might pose a problem. Say the user enrolled while at home and later records a message while on the go in a busy city environment, the system might have troubles making sure it's actually the same person speaking. The signal to noise ratio is definitely going to be one of your main issues. Small tip: depending on the distance of the microphone to the mouth, the ratio will be quite different. You'll get way better result when the user puts the phone close to its face like in a regular phone conversation than when the user looks at the screen while recording the message.

Voice variability and signal to noise ratio are probably the main reasons behind false negative results.

Hopefully, you now have a better understanding of the challenges awaiting you and I can start sharing some pointers for open source and commercial libraries.

AFAIK, there are no open source libraries that includes fraudster detection...
You may want to check Nuance Communication for state-of-the-art. There are plenty other vendors, just check with Google, I only mentioned Nuance because of it's reputation.

There is an OSS library called Alize (written in C++, under LGPL license) which uses an algorithm called MFCC (Mel Frequency Cepstrum Coefficients). MFCC is known to bring excellent results. Expect a steep learning curve as this software is aimed at researchers willing to improve the state-of-the-art on this topic and the vocabulary used is very specific.

I wrote an OSS library named Recognito (Java, Apache 2.0) aimed at regular developers so you should be able to test it in a matter of minutes. The lib is very young and I first focused on it's API before improving the algorithms. The algorithm I use for the moment is called Linear Predictive Coding (LPC) and is known to bring good results (and I do have good results, provided recordings yield the same level of quality :-)). I'm currently in the process of releasing a new version including a likelihood coefficient in the match results. MFCC implementation is on the road map.
There is plenty of javadoc and the code should be very straightforward...
https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito

Recognito has a dependency on javax.sound packages for audio file handling. You may want to check this post for what it takes to use it in Android: [Voice matching in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443124/voice-matching-in-android/22445304#22445304)

Given many people need something for android, I'll do something about it in the near future instead of saying how one should modify the lib :-)

HTH

Comment: This post should be a bolg article. Nice one.