# Android Compare two sounds

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, fft, audio-processing, spectrogram

I have two arrays of two sounds (two spectrograms).
These sounds are Resolution 512.
I need a way to know if these two sounds are alike?

The first voice is received by a user who says "Hey Ario"
The second voice is received in a service that seeks speech similar to the first voice, "Hey Ario".
like "Ok Google!".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two voice in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422939/compare-two-voice-in-android)